# Script to fetch results from data explorer

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Is it possible to fetch data results from data explorer without going on the page ?

The thing is that there is a captcha to prevent *spam queries* so I'm not sure it's possible.[image]

But is there a workaround to get this data ? Can I log in somehow and act as a non-anonymous user ?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, the data dump might be interesting to you.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby What is it ?

Comment: As the name suggesst, [it is a complete data dump of the sites](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump).

Comment: You probably want to support this request: [Running queries to StackExchange Data Explorer from anywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54902)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. It's there to prevent this sort of thing to reduce the load on the server. If this wasn't in place, I could just write a script that runs queries remotely.

You may want to look into the StackOverflow [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yeah tought so.. It's bad since I would love to query it and display result on my user profil. I thought it could be done somehow since it would be on my profil so I could somehow pass my account parameters to the query. *loooongshot*

Comment: @returnPhaDaPhunk Imagine that a call would need to be made every time someone looks at your profile. Not a good idea.

Comment: Too bad you're right on this :( thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SE API](http://api.stackexchange.com/). Write an app that presents the information that you wish to display in image form. Make it so that others may use it as well on their profiles by changing the image query string. Finally, [get an API](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) key to get rid of throttling.