# Can I use Data Explorer from my site, and if so: can I avoid the captcha?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Yesterday, I was playing with the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/154914/stackoverflow-annual-stats). So, I thought why not develop some more interesting SQL queries and implement into your site. So, my questions are:

- Am I allowed to execute queries to Data Explorer from my site?
- The first time I used it, it asked for a CAPTCHA. Do, I have to take permission somewhere to prevent asking of captcha's?

Comment: A DE query is expensive to run. The captcha is there to stop bots from spamming it.

Comment: You can always download the data and run the queries yourself.

Comment: IIRC you are asked for captchas if you are not logged in on Data explorer. You can login to data explorer to prevent captchas

Comment: If you're not doing some statistics, then maybe [the live API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) and [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) are more interesting.

Comment: API's are not something I am looking for. I need some magic of SQL

Answer (score 4):

It's not so much that you aren't allowed as it is that there's no real method for doing so. However, if you're interested in having something like this, there's an [existing feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54902/running-queries-to-stackexchange-data-explorer-from-anywhere) to implement this kind of functionality.